# How to convert an image .jpg to GeoTIFF (with georeference)

Tags: metadata, geotiff-tiff, matlab

I did a linear regression of 26 images with the same structure (rows, columns, resolution, DATUM, projection) using MATLAB. The result that I have got is an image without spatial reference, other resolution and less columns and rows (I loose all the metadata).

How can I copy the metadata from the input images to the output image?

Comment: What do you have as input images? GeoTIFFs, something with image + world file, something else?

Comment: Input images are GeoTIFFs.

Comment: You can save the GeoTIFF info with listgeo http://web.archive.org/web/20160817035938/http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/listgeo.html and write it into a new tiff with geotifcp http://geotiff.maptools.org/geotifcp.html

Comment: Thank you but I have problems to download listgeo. Do you know if there is any script to do it with MATLAB?

Comment: Both comes with OSGeo4W if that is an option for you.

Comment: Why is your  output  smaller than the input images? Is that the expected behaviour of your  code?